# If my .vue files are all the same, how can I avoid repetition?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, npm, dry, babel-polyfill

I am new to Vue and there is a lot I like about it, but I do not like putting my templates, scripts, and styles all in the same file.

Instead I'd rather split the concerns by doing:

```
<template src="./template.html"></template>
<script lang="ts" src="./script.ts"></script>
<style lang="scss" scoped src="./style.scss"></style>
```

As such my directory for each component will look like

[image]

If I do this, however, then it seems to me that there should be a way to make the .vue file itself completely unnecessary.

There should be a way to tell tell my build tools that if it is looking for x/x.vue and this file is not found, to just fill in the gap with the code above.

Without getting into any debates as to the pros and cons of this approach, how can I do this?

For whatever it is worth, I am using vue version 3.9.3 and am prepared to add whatever npm dependencies are necessary/desirable to the project.

To be clear, while I am also open to modifying my import statements, this is not my goal.  My goal is to eliminate the need for creating and maintaining the .vue files which are all expected to be identical.  (The ideal solution should use the file if it does happen to exist, in case for whatever reason, we want to build that component differently.)

To be even more clear, I am not looking for a solution which will change the architecture of my components.  I am looking for a meta-programming solution which will fill in code which can be implied to exist without anyone needing to write potentially hundreds of identical implementations.

Comment: What I do is to use the `.vue` file only for the `<template>` and to load the needed `.js` or `.css/.scss` files. This way I leave it to 3 files only and not having too much repetition by mixing 2 responsibilities in one file: templating and importing.

Comment: By the way this package is doing something similar to what you want: https://github.com/pksunkara/vue-builder-webpack-plugin

Comment: @iivannov, that sounds _exactly_ like what I want to do.  Will try it.  :-)

Comment: In this case I'll post it as an answer to be more visible. Maybe it will be useful for someone else too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a package doing something similar to what you want to achieve by leveraging webpack compiling the separate files into a single Vue component: https://github.com/pksunkara/vue-builder-webpack-plugin

What I perosnally do is to use the `.vue` file for defining the `<template>` and also to load the needed `.js` or `.css/.scss` files. This way I leave it down to only three files and still not having too much repetition by mixing two responsibilities in one file: templating and importing

```
<template>
   <p>Some code here</p>
</template>

<script src="./path_to_script.js"></script>
<style src="./path_to_styles.css"></style>
```

After checking the official documentation it seems the above is the currently idiomatic way of doing it: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html#What-About-Separation-of-Concerns

Comment: Looks like what I'm looking for.  I'll accept after I've had a chance to verify it works.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

i suggest a solution is to create a folder with the component name like `ProductForm` and inside it add the three files (template, script and style) and add another one which should be called `index.js` where you put

```
  <template src="./template.html"></template>
  <script lang="ts" src="./script.ts"></script>
  <style lang="scss" scoped src="./style.scss"></style>
```

to use the component import it like :

```
  import ProductForm from './components/ProductForm'
```

this automatically load `index.js` file without mentioning it in the import statement.

Comment: I think we might be misunderstanding each other.  This would delete a few characters from the import, yes.  But, unless I am misunderstanding you, I'd still need to repeat index.js for every folder, which would have exactly the same content as ProductForm.vue would have.  While less characters in the import statement is a plus, I want that the redundant .vue files should not need to exist at all.

Comment: i think using some patterns should like builder design pattern solve your problem, try to read [this article](https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/implementing-the-builder-pattern-in-vue-listings/)

Comment: Cheers for the link, but I don't really see how the builder pattern can be used to remove a file from a directory.  It is inherently the wrong level of abstraction for this particular issue.

Comment: i watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7YZ5DwlLSt8) before and i see that he mentioned something concerns loading files using webpack and lodash ...

Comment: what does that have to do with the price of tea in China?